# How should I conceptualize a right fold vs a left fold?

Tags: functional-programming, fold

Should I conceptualize a right fold as "folding the list *to* the right" or as "folding a list *from* the right"?

In other words, does a right fold go from *left-to-right* or from *right-to-left*?

Comment: Not an exact duplicate, but for Haskell see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3950508/haskell-foldr-and-foldl-further-explanation-and-example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Right fold goes **from** right to left.

Left fold goes from the left, like you read a text - from left to right.